# How to move files (images) into sites/default/files folder in Drupal 7

Tags: php, file, drupal-7, node-modules

I am saving images into `product_images` folder which is in **imagesdb** module, but I want to move this folder into `imagesdb/sites/default/files` folder.

Currently my code is:

```
if(file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT ."\product_images\\".$file)){
   $query = db_select('network_drive_listing','n')
      ->fields('n')
      ->condition('filetype' , $pathInfo['dirname'])
      ->execute();

   $fileTimestampFromDB = 0;

   while($record = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
      $fileTimestampFromDB = strtotime($record['file_timestamp']);
   }

   if($fileTimestampFromDB < strtotime($fileTimestamp)){
      $this->copyFileFromDrive($source_dir,$file);
   }else{

  }
}else{
   $this->copyFileFromDrive($source_dir,$file);
}
```

How can I move this folder into required destination so I can save my images into it?

Comment: you want to scan all files from `.\product_images` and move them all to `imagesdb/sites/default/files` ??

Comment: yes exactly i want this

Comment: there should be folder of product_images in imagesdb/sites/default/files

Comment: `mv ./product_images/* imagesdb/sites/default/files` execute

Comment: is it linux command? cannot i moved with code?

Comment: yes, this is a linux command is you server linux based or windows based ?

Comment: it is windows based